# Types in interfaces c#

Tags: java, c#, interface, extends

In java it's seems to be working if I have something like, but in the c# version:

```
 public interface MyIterator<T>: IEnumerator<T>
 {
    BaseClass<T> GetBaseClass();
 }
```

And :

```
   public interface IBaseClass<T>: IEnumerator<T>{
         bool Remove(T e);

        IEnumerator<T> Search(T e); 

        bool Contains(T e);

        bool IsEmpty();

        int Size();
   }
```

But in the implementation I have:

```
  public abstract class BaseClass<T> : IBaseClass<T>
    {  

  public MyIterator<T> Search(T e)
        {
..}
```

It doesn't allow me to have a different returned type, the only one allowed is `IEnumerator<T>` (from the interface).I know it's a little bit wired but this is how it is required in the given context. Example, other class like:

```
public class SpecializedContainer<T> : BaseClass<T>
```

will use BaseClass)

Comment: Um, your first code snippet is invalid - you haven't shown what `E` and `T` are at all. I assume they're meant to be type parameters somewhere, but you haven't shown them...

Comment: @Jon  Both T ..generic type , I'll edit my post

Comment: But you still haven't declared `T` as a type parameter anywhere. Did you mean `MyIterator<T>`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't just copy-paste the code and I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a type parameter, your definition of `IBaseClass` should have a type parameter `T` (unless they are part of another class).

Are you sure `IBaseClass` implements `IEnumerator<T>`? Usually it would implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

> It doesn't allow me to have a different returned type, the only one allowed is IEnumerator(from the interface).

That is unavoidable for the interface implementation, however explicit interface implementations allow you to have a separate public method.

Simply create two methods, a `public` one that returns `MyIterator<T>` and an explicit interface implementation that returns `IEnumerator<T>`.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> : IBaseClass<T>
{
    public MyIterator<T> Search(T e)
    {
        //Do something here
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IBaseClass<T>.Search(T e)
    {
        return Search(e);
    }
}
```

This will cause the type to be `MyEnumerator<T>` for calls to `BaseClass<T>.Search` and `IEnumerator<T>` for calls to `IBaseClass<T>.Search` (as required by the interface). Note of course that in either case the actual value will be of type `MyEnumerator<T>`.